# Looking for (very) fast approximate matching of (sub-)timeseries

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, time-series, matching, sequences

I'm dealing with a huge database of timeseries. A value is saved every n milliseconds. A new timeseries must be checked against old timeseries already in the DB.

At this moment I'm stucked as every solution is expensive like O(n²).

Below I have some pictures, showing short timeseries (gray and orange) which are a match. The algorithm should be able to identify such matches without beeing to accurate as I need speed. A approximation would be enough.

I've studied some paper out in the net dealing with "longest common subsequence problem" or "Dynamic time warping". But either dealing with perfect measurements or perfect sizes or beeing O(n²).

1. perfect match of two timeseries (gray and orange)
   [image]
2. inaccurate new measurement (orange) but still a match
   [image]
3. a short new measurement (orange) but still a match
   [image]
4. a huge new measurement (orange) but still a match
   [image]
5. a new measurement with failures (orange) but still a match
   [image]

Comment: The bitap algorithm seems to achieve a similar thing in text searching, maybe you can adapt it?

Comment: Yes, I could adapt an alphabet. I've took a look at Wikipedia regarding [bitap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm) and found a [paper by Gene Meyer](http://www.win.tue.nl/~jfg/educ/bit.mat.pdf) which is quite interesting. But I can't find any implementation. Is there any out in the net?

Comment: If you actually read that Wikipedia page, you'd see that bitap is already implemented in `agrep`.

Comment: I've read it but as i understand bitap is for "shorter" strings. My strings would be much longer, so I would be glad about an enhanced bitap implementation G. Myers proposed.

Answer (score 2):

The amortized time for DTW is less than O(N)

Doing this at 100,000Hz would be very easy

Look at this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_qLzMMuVQg